# How do you click an anchor tag link using rselenium and rvest in R?

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, rvest

I have been practicing web-scraping in R with rselenium and rvest packages. So, for logging into many websites, a sign in button is there, which when clicked a pop-up window opens asking for the user id and password. I have been trying the following codes to click that anchor tag where sign in link is present, but none is working.

This is the html of the anchor tag (example)

```
<a href="/profile/login_input.htm?userOriginHook=HEADER_SIGNIN_LINK" class="track-click gd-btn-locked-transparent susiLink sign-in strong nowrap" target="_top" data-ga-lbl="Sign In"> Sign In</a>
```

These are the codes I have been trying :

1.

```
user<-remDr$findElement(using = 'href',"/profile/login_input.htm?userOriginHook=HEADER_SIGNIN_LINK")
user$sendKeysToElement(list("",key="enter"))
```

2.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Sign In']")).click()
```

3.

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign In")).click()
```

4.

```
remDr$findElement(xpath="//a[contains(text(),'Sign In')]")).click()
```

Mostly, I am getting errors like unexpected symbol in this line

How to go about this? And how to send my user-id and password after pop up window opens? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide the website address so that I can try to help? Which is the website you try to navigate and login?

Comment: https://www.glassdoor.co.in/index.htm

Comment: Let me know how it goes with the answer below. It works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

In case you want to click on the *Sign in* button instead of straight navigating to its web address you can do the whole process as follows:

```
page<-"https://www.glassdoor.co.in"
remDr$navigate(page)
accept_cokies_btn <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", '//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')
accept_cokies_btn$clickElement()
signin <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", '//*[@id="TopNav"]/nav/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/a')
signin$clickElement()
```

And after this same as previously for submitting your username and password:

```
username_btn <- remDr$findElement(using ="name" , "username")
username_btn$sendKeysToElement(list("add username here"))
pass_btn <- remDr$findElement(using = "name", "password")
pass_btn$sendKeysToElement(list("add password here", "\uE007"))
```

Note that I have added the click on one more button; the *cookies accept button*.

Comment: Hey Yach, so your code is sending my user id and password to the sign up form on the page. The sign in button is at the top which needs to be clicked for logging in for already registered users.

Comment: Why would you need to necessarily click on it since you can just navigate to it using its address?

Comment: I'm posting an alternative in case you want to click instead of navigate

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I was specifically asking for button click because it would help me navigate through other websites also. The code works perfectly.

Comment: Glad it he generally helps you, I actually suspected that most of your focus was how to click a button. But did it work? Because I just realised that it actually submits the username and password information not to the anchor page but the previous. In case you need a specific workaround I just updated the code in my answer to solve this issue.

Comment: You can inspect the $findElement function more here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/seleniumPipes/versions/0.3.7/topics/findElement